# How to return all except last 2 characters of a string?

Tags: javascript, string, substring, slice, substr

```
id = '01d0';
document.write('<br/>'+id.substr(0,-2));
```

How can I take a string like '01d0`and get the`01` (all except the last two chars)?

In PHP I would use `substr(0,-2)` but this doesn't seem to work in JavaScript.

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 150, accepted):

You are looking for `slice()` (also [see MDC](http://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice))

```
id.slice(0, -2)
```

Comment: The `slice()` is right. I'm always surprised by how few people know about it and its useful negative offsets.

Answer (score 11):

Try `id.substring(0, id.length - 2);`

Answer (score 2):

```
var str = "031p2";
str.substring(0, str.length-2);
```

See : http://jsfiddle.net/GcxFF/

Answer (score 2):

Something like:

```
id.substr(0, id.length - 2)
```

The first parameter of *substr* is the starting index. The second parameter is how many characters to take.